# handling nulls in c#

Tags: c#

I have an object like this:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string Object.Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Object.Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm writing a custom JSON converter and I'm serializing this object like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> OutputJson = new Dictionary<string, object>();

OutputJson.Add("TheProp1", MyObject.Prop1.Trim());
```

If for some reason `Prop1` is `null`, will the code encode `TheProp1` as `""` or will it crash?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled about the "Object.Prop1" syntax. If MyObject did implement an interface called "Object", then OK, but otherwise? If "Object" is an interface, better call it "IObject".

Comment: `I'm writing a custom JSON converter` Why? `OutputJson.Add("TheProp1", MyObject.Prop1.Trim())` doesn't seem to be a nice way

Comment: @L.B: what I have works but if there's a nicer way, I'm interested. What do you suggest?

Comment: @frenchie, you can use one of the good json serializers for ex., JavaScriptSerializer, DataContractJsonSerializer, fastJSON, SimpleJson, Json.Net, Jsonfx, etc. My favorite is http://json.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `Prop1` is `null` your code will throw a `NullReferenceException`. You need to test if `Prop1` is null before calling `Trim`:

```
MyObject.Prop1 == null ? "" : MyObject.Prop1.Trim()
```

Or you can do it more concisely with the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
(MyObject.Prop1 ?? "").Trim()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this is to use private member to handle the property values of properties where you need a default value rather than null

```
Class MyObject
{
     private string _prop1 = String.Empty;

     public string Object.Prop1 { 
          get
           {
                return _prop1;
            } 
           set
           {
                _prop1 = value;
            } 
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will crash with a `NullReferenceException`, since you can't call `Trim` on `null`. You could do this instead:

```
OutputJson.Add("TheProp1", MyObject.Prop1 == null ?
                               string.Empty :
                               MyObject.Prop1.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that a null is not an empty string.  If you want to insure that this is going to work simply wrap the Value of the add in an if and insert your empty string as the null place holder.  Of course you'll need to take the appropriate action when you decode your json.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need polymorphic behaviour for MyObject you can declare it as a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of a class. It will have value semantic and every value will be initialize using its default. I am assuming inside your class you have just struct type (eg. int, string, double).

Answer (score 0):

you can use DBNull class in filling the object

```
UserName = DBNull.Value != reader["UserName"] ? reader["UserName"].ToString() : default(string);
```